# Fun and Fix in ML

Tags: ml

I understand  fun and fix in ML as :

**fix** calculates least fix point or simply can allow use of same name inside the call  and **fun** allows to explicitly control scope of the variable also fun is used for non-recursive versions.

I might be wrong. Can anyone specify the difference between fun and fix in ML.

Comment: One difference is that `fun` is part of SML but `fix` isn't. What language are you talking about?

Comment: SML. I'm reading paper "Dependent types in practical programming". when It extends Mini-Ml with pattern matching it uses this fix thing.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain a bit more in your question. For example, does the author give an SML implementation of `fix`? If so, what? If not, is there a nonstandard version of ML which does implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That paper introduces a mini-language, called ML₀, which presents two constructs, `lam` and `fix`. The first is for non-recursive function expressions, while the second is a fixpoint combinator that allows defining recursive functions.

`fun` is used later on as part of a different language that's meant as a surface language for use by the programmer. `fun` should be desugared to `lam` and `fix` calls, as shown in Figure 5 of the paper.

Comment: Completely clear. Yes Its not present in ML0 syntax.  Thanks